# Is this union of intervals is a borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets

I have to show that $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}\right]$$ and $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[n,n+\frac{4}{n^2}\right]$$
both are Borel sets.

I thought that unions of closed intervals are always Borel. Am i missing something?

Comment: Indeed, countable union of Borel sets are borel.

Comment: So in order to show it, what would be sufficient?

Comment: First of all, do you know the fact I wrote above? What is your definition of a Borel set?

Comment: The Borel sets together form a $\sigma$-algebra, which is by definition a collection of sets closed under complements and countable unions.

Comment: Yes i know the fact you wrote. My definition of a borel set is: The members of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra is called Borel sets. The Borel-$\sigma$-algebra is the one generated by the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Should I check for the three properties of a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: It is enough for you to prove that closed intervals are Borel. This is easy because they are complements of open sets and the Borel sets are closed under complementation. Then it can be concluded immediately that countable unions of closed intervals are Borel too.

Comment: @Severin Schraven: Also, an arbitrary union of intervals of positive length (each of which can be open or closed or half closed) is Borel. This can be proved using the Vitali covering lemma, and I believe this was a somewhat common Ph.D. qualifying exam problem at Indiana University in the 1970s and/or early 1980s. In fact, by more elementary methods one can show that any such union is an $F_{\sigma}$ set --- see Lemma 1 on p. 238 of [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm44/fm44121.pdf) (also the proof of Theorem 2.3 on p. 42 of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821869906)).

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{open sets are Borel}\stackrel{1}{\to}\text{closed intervals are Borel}\stackrel{2}{\to}\text{countable unions of closed intervals are Borel}$$

Collection of Borel sets is $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets, so:

- 0) open sets are Borel.
- 1) since the collection is closed under complements.
- 2) since the collection is closed under countable unions.

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you have any hint on how to determine the Lebesgue measure of the sets? By this time in my course the Lebesgue measure is only defined on the half-open intervals.

Comment: $[a,b)\subseteq[a.b]\subseteq[a,b+\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$ so that $b-a=\lambda([a,b)\leq\lambda([a,b])\leq\lambda([a,b+\epsilon)=b-a+\epsilon$. This leads to $\lambda([a,b])=b-a$. The unions in your question are "almost" disjoint (have a close look for small $n$) and in that case you can apply that a measure is $\sigma$-additive.

Answer (score 0):

First time answering here so pardon any mistakes in protocol.  Here's a start.  You can rewrite the closed sets as countable intersections of open sets.  Then you could take some additional steps and probably use complements of closed sets to complete the proof.  Hopefully my Tex conversion tool works.

$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{{}}\left[ n,n+\frac{1}{{{n}^{2}}} \right]=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\left( n-\frac{1}{k},n+\frac{1}{{{n}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{k} \right)}}$

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you have any hint on how to determine the Lebesgue measure of the sets? By this time in my course the Lebesgue measure is only defined on the half-open intervals.

Comment: My problem is, that I dont know what to do with $\frac{1}{k}$ when calculating the Lebesgue measure. Since I know that i can be defined on closed intervals I dont see what to do with the $\frac{1}{k}$.